# Embedding SurrealDB in Rust with its HTTP API

Tags: surrealdb

I am writing a server application with embedded SurrealDB and would like to allow external, 3rd party clients (e.g.: Surrealist) to connect to the embedded DB too.
Is that possible without implementing all endpoints of [SurrealDB's REST API](https://docs.surrealdb.com/docs/integration/http) in my code?

I used [this](https://docs.surrealdb.com/docs/embedding/rust) code from SurrealDB Docs as a template and included it into my server App. It works well. My app can access the embedded DB, but the HTTP API is not available for external clients.